# Beginner Program Help Python3- String not callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a simple program that allows the user to type in their name and birthday and the bot will type back different responses based on the user input.

I had the program working before I tinkered with the # that you see at the bottom but now it does not work.

This is my first program so any help would be great! trying to self-teach (which is rly hard)

I am trying to set the variables to the input that the user puts.  I had the whole program working at one point but I am not sure what happened or what the error means

[image: Code]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: would you mind copying your code to your post, rather as text and not as an screenshot?

Comment: In StackOverflow, you have the option to simply add the code/text/error in text and format it accordingly. So refrain from using pictures for codes, errors.

Comment: @Nick that's not necessary

Comment: Most likely, overwrote the value print somewhere above in the code.

Answer (score 1):

For assigning Strings in Python do this:

```
my_birthday1 = "whatever"
```

and not

```
my_birthday1 = ("whatever")
```

because `defName("abc")` is used to call some function `defName` and passing `"abc"` to it.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned it up a bit and it works fine.

```py
name = input("What's your name? ")
print("Hello " + name + ", my name is Sam.")

my_birthday1 = "06.04"
my_birthday2 = "06/04"
birthday = input("What day of the year is your birthday? ")

if str(birthday) == my_birthday1 or str(birthday) == my_birthday2:
    print(birthday + " is also my birthday.")
else:
    print(birthday + "! That's cool!")
```